# How can I avoid the "FrameHitTest while not tracking. Returning empty list. error message" in ARCore?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I am using ARCore and Sceneform. I receive a lot of error messages while my application tries to track images. 
Everything works fine, except that I have bad performance on longer runs of the app and I think it could relate to these error messages.

Maybe I need to regulate the tracking interval somehow?

Here is an cutout of these messages:

```
I/native: plane_detection_manager.cc:204 Failed to get device pose.
E/native: session.cc:1095 FrameHitTest while not tracking. Returning empty list.
E/native: session.cc:1095 FrameHitTest while not tracking. Returning empty list.
I/native: distribute.cc:92 No keypoints to prune.
I/native: plane_detection_manager.cc:204 Failed to get device pose.
E/native: session.cc:1095 FrameHitTest while not tracking. Returning empty list.
E/native: session.cc:1095 FrameHitTest while not tracking. Returning empty list.
E/native: session.cc:1095 FrameHitTest while not tracking. Returning empty list.
I/native: distribute.cc:92 No keypoints to prune.
I/native: plane_detection_manager.cc:204 Failed to get device pose.
E/native: session.cc:1095 FrameHitTest while not tracking. Returning empty list.
E/native: session.cc:1095 FrameHitTest while not tracking. Returning empty list.
E/native: session.cc:1095 FrameHitTest while not tracking. Returning empty list.
I/native: distribute.cc:92 No keypoints to prune.
I/native: image_target_detector.cc:187 Input query has too few keypoints.
E/native: planar_target_tracking_manager.cc:353 generic::unavailable: redwood::FAILED_PRECONDITION: VIO is not tracking
E/native: session.cc:1095 FrameHitTest while not tracking. Returning empty list.
I/native: plane_detection_manager.cc:204 Failed to get device pose.
E/native: session.cc:1095 FrameHitTest while not tracking. Returning empty list.
E/native: session.cc:1095 FrameHitTest while not tracking. Returning empty list.
```

I am running sceneform under the following configuration and use an augmented image database:

```
config.setUpdateMode(Config.UpdateMode.LATEST_CAMERA_IMAGE);
config.setFocusMode(Config.FocusMode.AUTO);
```

Answer (score 1):

This are no errors, just messages about what is happening. 
ARCore try to track all the time, that's the reason it use a lot of memory and is heavy for the CPU.

He is trying to find surfaces and keep trying.

Probably this is a hardware issue. Today I use S9 and Pixel 2 XL to test my apps but it get hot sometimes and on Nexus 2 it has a bad performance.

Today ARCore perfomance depends too much of the device that you are using

Comment: I use the Google Pixel. It calms me down to hear that I am not the only one with these problems. 

I was hoping that there is a possibility to lower the tracking frequence to relieve the CPU a little bit. But I couldn't manage to find a solution for that until now.

Comment: @J.Hegg I would say that probably you can do this, but shouldn't. But these are not errors anyway. Maybe after the device found a lot of surfaces it try less, but I don't think so.